# Prove/disprove : $\left(1+\frac{(-1)^{n}}{\sqrt{n}} \right)^{-1}=\left(1-\frac{(-1)^{n}}{\sqrt{n}}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \right)$

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

Why we have that 
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} \right)^{-1} & =\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\left(1-\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}+O\left(\frac{1}n\right) \right) \tag{$E_1$} \\
\end{align*}$$
insted of $$\left(1-\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}+o\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right) \right) \tag{$E_2$} ?$$
Is that because we have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$? But this is wrong!

- Could someone explain to me why we have $E_1$ instead of $E_2$

[image]

Comment: I don't think $E_1$ is true. $O(1/n)$ is true, but $o(1/n)$ is not ture.

Answer (score 2):

By Taylor expansion,
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}} &= 1+ \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{n} + o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\\
&=1+ \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

By the Taylor series expansion, as $u \to 0$, we have
$$
\frac1{1+u}=1-u+O(u^2)
$$ giving, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\frac1{1+\dfrac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}}=1-\dfrac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}+O\left(\dfrac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^2=1-\dfrac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}+O\left(\dfrac1n\right),
$$ and
$$
\dfrac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\frac1{1+\dfrac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}}=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}-\dfrac1n+O\left(\dfrac1{n^{3/2}}\right).
$$

Comment: is this  hold for big and small o

Comment: We have a big O which is small o: $O\left(\dfrac1{n^{3/2}}\right)= o\left(\dfrac1n\right)$. Do you see it?

Comment: so is that hold for small i mean in french  ( négligeable devant une autre ( petiti o ) )

Comment: @Yacob Your $(E_1)$ is not true, your $(E_2)$ is right as I've shown above.